# Pandas dataframe: Efficiently select cases

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe being called `datafr`:

```
ID  Step Category  Price
1     1        A    500
1     2        A    600
1     3        A    700
1     4        B    900
2     2        C    900
2     1        C   1000
2     4        C   1200
2     3        C   1400
3     2        C   1600
3     3        C    200
4     1        A    100
```

I now want to select only those IDs, which contain a 1 for column "Step". So the final dataframe should look like this:

```
ID  Step Category  Price
1     1        A    500
1     2        A    600
1     3        A    700
1     4        B    900
2     2        C    900
2     1        C   1000
2     4        C   1200
2     3        C   1400
4     1        A    100
```

So the ID 3 should not be included, as it has no record with step equal to 1.

My approach is to first select those entries which contain step 1 and save it to another dataframe. Then merge this back, so that I have it as an extra column on which I can filter:

```
datafr_step1=datafr.loc[datafr['Step'] == 1]
df_step1_renamed=datafr_step1.rename(columns={'Step': 'Step_1_values'})
print(df_step1_renamed)
df_merged=pd.merge(datafr,df_step1_renamed[['ID','Step_1_values']],on='ID',how='left')
print(df_merged)
final_df=df_merged.loc[df_merged['Step_1_values'] == 1]
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Step_1_values Category  Price
0    1              1        A    500
5    2              1        C   1000
10   4              1        A    100
    ID  Step Category  Price  Step_1_values
0    1     1        A    500            1.0
1    1     2        A    600            1.0
2    1     3        A    700            1.0
3    1     4        B    900            1.0
4    2     2        C    900            1.0
5    2     1        C   1000            1.0
6    2     4        C   1200            1.0
7    2     3        C   1400            1.0
8    3     2        C   1600            NaN
9    3     3        C    200            NaN
10   4     1        A    100            1.0
    ID  Step Category  Price  Step_1_values
0    1     1        A    500            1.0
1    1     2        A    600            1.0
2    1     3        A    700            1.0
3    1     4        B    900            1.0
4    2     2        C    900            1.0
5    2     1        C   1000            1.0
6    2     4        C   1200            1.0
7    2     3        C   1400            1.0
10   4     1        A    100            1.0
```

It works, but I think this is not a good approach. I have a quite large dataframe, so I would be interested in an efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `any` to select a group if there is any 1 in it:

```
datafr[datafr['Step'].eq(1).groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')]
```

output:

```
    ID  Step Category  Price
0    1     1        A    500
1    1     2        A    600
2    1     3        A    700
3    1     4        B    900
4    2     2        C    900
5    2     1        C   1000
6    2     4        C   1200
7    2     3        C   1400
10   4     1        A    100
```

Comment: I think it should be datafr[datafr['Step'].eq(1).groupby(datafr['ID']).transform('any')] so not df but datafr. I tried it with my large dataset and I get an error: "ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values"

Comment: @PSt yes it should be `datafr` I already had changed the name ;)

Comment: I am getting "ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values" when running it on my large dataset.

Comment: @Pst where do you have NaNs? Can you update your example? What is the full error?

Comment: @Pst I think you have NaNs in ID, then you should use `df[df['Step'].eq(1).groupby(df['ID'], dropna=False).transform('any')]`

Answer (score 3):

If performance is important avoid use `groupby`, filter values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for `ID` with `1` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = datafr[datafr['ID'].isin(datafr.loc[datafr['Step'] == 1, 'ID'].unique())]
print (df)
    ID  Step Category  Price
0    1     1        A    500
1    1     2        A    600
2    1     3        A    700
3    1     4        B    900
4    2     2        C    900
5    2     1        C   1000
6    2     4        C   1200
7    2     3        C   1400
10   4     1        A    100
```

**Details**:

```
print (datafr.loc[datafr['Step'] == 1, 'ID'])
0     1
5     2
10    4
Name: ID, dtype: int64

print (datafr['ID'].isin(datafr.loc[datafr['Step'] == 1, 'ID']))
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8     False
9     False
10     True
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I tried it and I get an error: "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.61 GiB for an array with shape (18, 11969485) and data type object"

Comment: @PSt - Can you test `df = datafr[datafr['ID'].isin(datafr.loc[datafr['Step'] == 1, 'ID'].unique())]` ?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I tried, but I still get the memoryerror.